# Read UART continuously without blocking host application

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, embedded, embedded-linux

I have been searching around and reading the documentation, but I am at the point where I need a little help. The use case is relatively simple, but the implementation is where I am stuck.

On one end is a wireless Xbee radio. This radio transmits a signal every 300ms. The payload of this signal consists of button states and joystick positions.

On the receiving end is a Linux based SBC running Ubuntu with an Xbee attached. For the sake of this post, I have combined the following into one single file and added a main for readability:

This code is based off the [Serial programming Guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "XbeeReceiver.h"

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

volatile int STOP = FALSE;
void signal_handler_IO(int status);
int wait_flag = TRUE;
int fileDescriptor = -1;

/* Constants */
const char *DEFAULT_PORT = "/dev/ttyTHS1";
const int DEFAULT_BAUD = B115200;

/* Prototypes */
struct N64_DTO queryController(int fd);
void init(const char *port, const int baud);
void setTermConfig(int fd, const int baud);
void signal_handler_IO(int status);
int openUART(const char *port);

void init(const char *port, const int baud) {

    fileDescriptor = openUART(port ? port : DEFAULT_PORT);
    setTermConfig(fileDescriptor, baud ? baud : DEFAULT_BAUD);

    while (STOP == FALSE) {
        if (wait_flag == FALSE) {
            struct N64_DTO controller = queryController(fileDescriptor);
            printf("\n\n\n Y Joystick:: %i \n", (signed char) controller.y);
            printf("X Joystick:: %i \n", (signed char) controller.x);
            /* I am supposed to set STOP to TRUE for this loop to stop, however I always want to read from the controller,
             which is why this is now blocking */
            wait_flag = TRUE;
        }
    }
}

struct N64_DTO queryController(int fd) {

    struct N64_DTO controller;
    int byteCount = read(fd, (char *) &controller, sizeof(struct N64_DTO));

    if (byteCount == -1) {
        printf("I'll handle this error later on");
        exit(1);
    }
    return controller;
}

void signal_handler_IO(int status) {
    printf("received SIGIO signal.\n");
    wait_flag = FALSE;
}

void setTermConfig(int fd, const int baud) {

    struct sigaction saio;
    saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
    sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&saio.sa_mask, SIGINT);
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
    sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);

    struct termios toptions;

    tcgetattr(fd, &toptions);
    cfsetspeed(&toptions, baud);

    /* man termios for individual definitions */
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    toptions.c_cc[VMIN] = sizeof(struct N64_DTO);
    toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions);
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
}

int openUART(const char *port) {

    return open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    init("/dev/ttyTHS1", 115200);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("This loop never prints..");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Although it needs more refactoring, this code works and gives me the expected output. However, now that I have the output, I would like to do something with it, i.e send as input to a motor controller etc. The problem is, due to the frequency of reads(300ms) the program is ultimately blocking any other routines from executing.

I went back to the drawing board a few weeks ago and started down a few different paths. I explored threading, signal handlers, leveraging poll/select API, and the possibility of creating a dedicates kernel module. Last week, for a different reason, I put the controller up on a scope and setup triggers for the rising edge of the signal. That’s when it hit me. What I want is an event driven model where the OS notifies me when a signal is detected on a particular serial port. I figured I would reach out and see if someone has experience in this area that would be willing to steer me in the right direction. I have been at this issue for a week and still have not made any progress. In the end, the goal is to continuously receive serial data from the port without blocking other parts of my applications(driving motors, moving servos).

Comment: for `true` and `false`, use the header file: stdbool.h

Comment: How big is the `struct N64_DTO`?   in general, it is much better to pass a pointer to a struct rather than the whole struct, especially if the struct will not fit into a (underlying architecture) register pair.

Comment: this line: `exit(1);` is handled in the header file: `stdlib.h` via the definition of: `EXIT_FAILURE` so could be more clearly written as: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the `read()` function will only input those bytes that are currently available, so the code should be (also) checking that `byteCount == sizeof(struct N64)DTO)`  and if less, then loop to read again, until either the byteCount <0 (and error) or byteCount==0.  if byteCount ==0 then check errno to assure no problem has occurred.

Comment: it would be better to change the line: `struct N64_DTO controller;` to `static struct N64_DTO controller;`  and use: `return &controller;`  Then any caller to that function should be modified to expect a pointer rather than the whole struct

Comment: suggest placing the accessing of the peripheral into a thread, then use a mutex to keep the accessing of the data from clashing between the main program and the thread.  Inside the thread, use a call to `select()` to wait for data from the peripheral, perhaps with a modest timeout value so the thread will not 'hang' on the `select()` forever.

Comment: do not depend on 'volatile' to stop the accessing to to the peripheral.  Rather, use a mutex

Comment: when modifying a serial port characteristics, always save the original characteristics, then when done using the port, restore the original characteristics.

Comment: the parameters to `main()`,  `argc` and `argv[]` are not used.  This results in the compiler outputting a message for each of those parameters.  Strongly suges changing the signature for `main()` to: `int main( void )`

Comment: this line: `printf("This loop never prints..");` has a problem:  `stdout` is buffered, so to get immediate output, either follow each call to `printf()` with a call to: `fflush( stdout );`   --or-- (preferred) modify the format string to: `printf("This loop never prints..\n");`   Notice the newline on the end of the format string.  Also, `printf()` is rather 'heavy duty' for this job, Suggest: `puts( "This loop never prints..\n");`

Comment: when there is/are unused parameter(s) in a function other than `main()`  then the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)parmName;`  for instance in: `signal_handler_IO()`, the `status` parameter is not used, so the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)status;`

Comment: the `read()` function returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int` So the line: `int byteCount = read(fd, (char *) &controller, sizeof(struct N64_DTO));`  Should be: `ssize_t byteCount = read(fd, (char *) &controller, sizeof(struct N64_DTO));`

Comment: in function: `openUART()`, the port is opened with the option: `O_NONBLOCK`  so any calls, later on, to `read()`  will immediately return.  therefore in function: `queryController()`, MUCH better to call `select()` before calling `read()` as the `read()` will return 0 a good portion of the time.

Comment: You mention using a thread, but have not explained why this is unsatisfactory - it is the obvious solution.  Perhaps you need t ask a question about why you threading solution did not work?  As it is this question is rather broad since there are several possible solutions.

Comment: Typically you should either use a thread doing a blocking read, or else combine the serial port with whatever other fd's you need to respond to into an fd_set and select() on them.